# How do I initialize weights to correspond with amount of inputs

Tags: pandas, numpy, neural-network

I'm new to Neural networks and I'm just wondering how I initialize my weights to be to the same amount of inputs I have. I obviously could do it manually (w1, w2...w30) but I was wondering if there was a quicker way to do this and for it to correspond to input value just using NumPy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy random method like this

```
np.random.rand(3,2)
```

This will create an array of random values having 3 rows and 2 columns.
For more information [visit this link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html)